# Where did I go wrong in simplifying $[ (p \vee q) \wedge \neg p ] \implies q$?

Tags: discrete-mathematics, proof-verification

[This](http://faculty.kfupm.edu.sa/ics/darwish/ICS253-Spring2015/exams/Exam1_Sample1.pdf) practice pdf which I found online presents the following as question #4 and asks students to simplify the logical expression as much as possible:

$[ (p \vee q) \wedge \neg p ] \implies q$

I did so on my own, but my final result does not match what they have listed in their own solution. Here are my steps:

1. $[ (p \vee q) \wedge \neg p ] \implies q$ ............**Given**
2. $\neg[ (p \vee q) \wedge \neg p ] \vee q $............**Conditional identity, 1**
3. $[\neg(p \vee q) \vee p] \vee q$............**DeMorgan's Law and double negation, 2**
4. $[(\neg p \wedge \neg q) \vee p] \vee q$............**DeMorgan's Law again, 3**
5. $[(\neg p \wedge \neg q)] \vee (p \vee q)$............**Associative Law, 4: $(a \vee b) \vee c = a \vee (b \vee c)$**

At this stage, I substituted $x$ for $(p \vee q)$ in order to apply the distributive law. The expression with that substitution looks like so:

$x \vee [\neg p \wedge \neg q]$

Moving on to the next step of my proof:

6. $(x \vee \neg p) \wedge (x \vee \neg q)$............**Distributive, 5**
7. $( p \vee q \vee \neg p) \wedge (p \vee q \vee \neg q)$
8. $(p \vee \neg p \vee q) \wedge (p \vee q \vee \neg q)$............**Commutative law, 7**
9. $(p \vee T) \wedge (p \vee T)$............**Complement law twice, 8**
10. $T \wedge T$............**Domination twice, 9**
11. $T$............**Identity, 10**

Is the online solution manual incorrect?

Comment: I haven't checked all of your working, but it is indeed true that the expression can be simplified to "T". (i.e. The original expression is a tautology.) The mistake in the solution manual is in the line where they apply the distributive law.

Comment: Ah, I guess I could have technically used a truth table to check my work. Thanks for confirming that it's a tautology!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Indeed the solution manual is wrong and you are correct, this statement is a tautology. But you can still simplify your work. Once you have line 3: $[(\lnot(p \vee q)) \vee p] \vee q$, you can simply apply the associative law and find
$$
[\lnot (p \vee q)] \vee (p \vee q).
$$

Comment: I can't figure out how you arrived at that particular expression on line 4.

Comment: I will edit my comment, it seems I made some typos.

Comment: Gotcha, that makes more sense. Thank you!